# App/game freezes completely while coroutine runs

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

My Android ARCore Unity app/game freezes when a coroutine runs, and then resumes once the coroutine finishes. The coroutine is in a script attached to a gameobject, and the coroutine is called in the Start() function. I have tried inserting `yield return null;` into more parts of the coroutine, which reduces the time of the pauses, but adds more pauses, resulting in very choppy (basically nonexistent) gameplay for a second or two after the object is instantiated. Could this be happening because ARCore does not support multithreaded rendering? If that is the case (or isn't) how can I fix this, so my coroutine runs (I guess 'in the background') after the object is instantiated and so it does not affect gameplay FPS?

Here is my code:

```c#
void Start() 
{
    StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator MyCoroutine ()
{
    yield return null;
    Transform[] allChildren = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
    {
        if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>())
        {
            if (!child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider>())
            {
                child.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
            }
        }
        child.gameObject.tag = "CenterObject";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coroutines seem to have an overhead when constructing them as discussed here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/startcoroutine-performance-cost.233623/

Given that you're instantiating objects I would suggest these paths:

- Change the coroutine into a simple function call, since you don't seem to be requiring any delay between iterations of the loop which is the primary idea of using a coroutine in Unity. You are also adding colliders and expecting gameplay to continue, which can cause unexpected behaviour if you need collisions to be registered.
- Instantiate prefabs which have colliders attached beforehand, if possible.
- Use object pooling where you would create the objects before gameplay starts and activate them when required, and disable them when they are destroyed, if necessary.

Comment: We are thinking on very similar paths :). This started as a simple function call but the performance issue existed, so I wanted to try a coroutine to do it after the object is instantiated, but now the only difference is the app freezes after the object becomes visible, rather than before.

The whole point of this script is just to save me time while working in the editor. This does not have to happen during gameplay. I might just turn this into a script that I can run on trigger in the editor to manipulate a prefab to my desired result.

Comment: I'm running this in the Editor using a function as a ContextMenu item. I think this is just a way better way to do this in general. I think I would have gone this route on my own without your help, but you pushed me in the right direction, so upvote and check-mark for you. Thanks!

Comment: Object pooling seems to be the proper solution here +1

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are caught looping within the coroutine. You need to move the yield to inside the loop:

```
IEnumerator MyCoroutine ()
{
    Transform[] allChildren = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
    {
        if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>())
        {
            if (!child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider>())
            {
                child.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
            }
        }
        child.gameObject.tag = "CenterObject";
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Even so, if this is a large number of children you are looping through, it may simply be a performance issue.

Comment: Giving this a shot!

Comment: There isn't a large amount of children, and this doesn't solve the problem, but it might help ever so slightly with performance. Since this is probably proper coroutine coding, I'll upvote this, but it isn't the solution for this specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers fixing your Coroutine:

Coroutines are not really multithreading! That's why your app freezes if there is a long task in the Coroutine.

The `yield return` of Coroutines just makes it easy/lazy to do a quick animation or something similar because the Coroutines kind of "remember" where they left and go on from this point (to say it in simple words) so you can run a lot of things apparently "parallel". But still it all runs in the same thread so actually it only seems to be executed parallel because everything is executed between two frames.

If you realy have a time consuming task you want to do in another thread than have a look into [async await](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/) which is Unity's real multithreading since Unity 2017.

However Unity is **not** thread save meaning most of the API can only be used in the main thread...

Comment: I was looking for something like this. But, I don't think this would work since ARCore requires multithreaded rendering to be disabled. Is that correct, or is there still a way to get it to work somehow?